# C bit masking AND operation issue

Tags: c

Im new to C and im having trouble understanding the usage of bit masking operations. For example i have the following code

```
if((input & 0x08)== 0)
{

 //Do....//

}
```

I took input to be the int value 00000111 , which is 7 in binary and hex, but when i do this comparison it evaluates as false (never entering the if statement).

here is what i understand and what should happen

```
          00000111  input
        & 00001000  0x08
         ------------
          00000000  answer
```

So my question is how can i get the correct output.

Comment: @cnicutar look, there is `==0` comparison, so it should.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko I misread, you're right.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. There must be some other bug (the input is not as expected, for example).

Comment: Are you *sure* `input` is 7? Where are you assigning it?

Comment: Also, are you sure you even reach the if? Also, are you sure that the `then`-branch is _not_ executed?

Comment: When you say the input is "the int value 00000111", do you mean somewhere in the code, you have `input = 00000111`?

Comment: @Walfie Hopefully not, but good point anyways.

Comment: You may want to add more information with the how `input` is declared and how you read `input` etc. Perhaps, just before the `if` statement, do `printf("\n%d\n", input);` which could help you figure out the issue.

Comment: Walfie what would be the difference if i use int = 00000111

Comment: @Vega512 That would be 111 in base 8 i.e. 73 in base 10. NOT integer 7 :)

Comment: And 73, in binary, is `1001001` with the 8-bit set.

Comment: And, in particular, 0000111 is equivalent to 0x49, and the 0x08 bit is set in 0x49. Remember, every time you write 0, you're writing an octal constant (not that it makes any difference).

Comment: That you all for the clarifications, i discovered the issue i was not taking in the correct value. Again, i appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 5):

```
int main(){
        int input = 7;

        if((input & 0x08)== 0)
        {
                printf("Hello!\n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

You are right, this program prints "Hello!".

There must be another problem in your code. Try always to create functions and test the most simple examples.

Try to print the value of `input` before the `if` statement.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm semi-expecting the question to be clarified soon